# Detect ASF version at compile time

Tags: atmel, atmelstudio

I want to be able to print in the console the ASF version that the microcontroller uses automatically.

Is there such a function or definition that provides the ASF version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found any definition anywhere in the code. However, in the project file, there is the version:

```
<content-extension eid="atmel.asf" uuidref="Atmel.ASF" version="3.30.1" />
```

As the project file is an XML file, you could write a script that gets the version and store it in an header file. This script should be launched pre build.

Comment: This is a very good temporary solution. Will use that until something else is found. Thank you so much!!! You made my day..
PS: I hope project file does stay still...